# Getting No usages found in the project while migrating a simple android app project into AndroidX?

Tags: android

I am beginner in android programming and learning android development through a ebook.When trying to migrate a simple project into androidx getting error "no usages found in the project".Using android studio 3.5.2 please help in detail if possible.

Answer (score 0):

by default, your project was made by androidx libraries.
if you again create a new project you will see **use androidx.* artifacts** is checked

migrate to androidx is for your previous projects, and as google said that all updates will be in androidx reference so you need to migrate to androidx to have full support.
check this link for more detail
    [AndroidX Overview](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx)